# How to capture heap memory usage while running an Android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance, memory

I built a video player app for Android. Now I'd like to capture info about its runtime (heap) memory usage.

Are there tools that I can use to capture and inspect this information?  I'm using Eclipse to develop my app; does it have any features or plugins that make this easy?

Comment: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

In `Android Studio` on the tool window `Android`, there is a button called `Dump Java Heap`

If you are still using `Eclipse`, you can open `DDMS` in the android sdk tools. You'll find a `Dump HPROF file` button. Then you use `hprof-conv` in sdk tools to convert the file format.

If you wanna dump heap in code, you can use this method `Debug.dumpHprofData(String fileName)`.

Comment: thank you. But how can I this data via the app and send back to my server as Analytics data ?